# Play music after lock screen

Tags: music, lock-screen

I have had the Nokia Lumia 500/600 series for a while now. When I first got it I was able to play youtube songs, lock the screen and still listen to the track.

Now when I lock the screen it stops the song, it is super annoying as unless I hold the phone the button will accidently press. Anyone know how to revert to the prior listed way.

Comment: Which app are you using to play from YouTube? Is that app allowed to run in the background (check in Battery Saver settings)?

Comment: If you are trying to open from music player it won't stop if you lock. Also check if the app is allowed to run at background.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this used to work in WP8.1 if I recall correctly, but doesn't anymore since Windows 10 Mobile (at least in the browser).

Two things you can do: 
- Try some of the YouTube-Apps in the store, some might be able to play audio in the background.
- Vote on this feature in the feedback hub. Microsoft really prioritizes its work on those votes.